# getting JSON data from server

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have the following code:

```
    let url:String = "https://some-service"

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = ""

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        //print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
        let dict = self.convertToDictionary(text: responseString!)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "adsDetails")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        //self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        //dump(dict)

        print("--------------------")
        dump(dict?["Birthday"]!)
        print("--------------------")

    }
    task.resume()
```

This is the convertToDictionary function.

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

this is the result dump

[image]

When I try to extract value of Img I get:
Type 'Any' Has no Subscript Members error and build fails

just want to add that dict?["Birthday"] is just one value from dict. dict has many other values that i will extract separately depending on the view i am on

please help me extract Img and text values.
Is there more then one set of values there?

thank you

Comment: Try to print as         dump(dict?["Birthday"]! ?? [String : AnyObject])

Comment: you should edit your question to show the code for the  `self.convertToDictionary(text: responseString!)`function

Comment: print your response and update question with log

Comment: @MichaelDautermann func added

Comment: I suggest you to use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. Once you practice with the stock libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to extract Img and text values:

```
    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    let dict = self.convertToDictionary(text: responseString!)

    if let birthday = dict?["Birthday"] as? [String: Any] {
        print(birthday["Img"])
        print(birthday["text"])
    }
```